# 2D Skeletal animations exported to SVG

Tags: 2d, skeletal-animation, export, svg

I would like to create skeletal animations, and [Synfig](https://github.com/synfig/synfig) looks quite promising.

This is a [video walk through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P65_ACqWxbQ)
of its "bones" feature, used to do skeletal animation.

Ticks all the boxes thus far, however, I couldn't find out if animations could be exported as SVG. The closest I got to this was [sif2svg](http://wiki.synfig.org/Sif2svg), which is a pure XSLT transform, and lists *"All sif elements aren’t supported, so it may have a lot of glitchs."* as a limitation.

- Has anyone had any experience here creating and exporting skeletal animations to **SVG**?
- Is Synfig capable of doing this?
- Are there alternative tools capable of doing this?